# Best way for optimising legend in R

Tags: r

I want to create an external .png plot in R.  The problem is that the legend may have over 100 different entries in it, but it may not (ie. it is very variable).  Basically I am trying to find the best way to create this plot in order to compensate for the potentially large number of elements that could be in the legend.

This is the script that I have at the moment:

```
png()
layout(rbind(1, 2), height=c(7, 1))
par(xpd=T)
xnum=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
xdesc=c("low","med2","high3","low4","low5","med6","high3","low2","high1","high1","low6","med27","high36","low44","low55","med62","high33","low332","high15","high16")
x=data.frame(xnum,xdesc)
y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
plot(x[,1],y,pch=as.numeric(x[,2]))
legend("bottomleft", inset=c(0,-0.2), legend=as.factor(unique(x[,2])),pch=as.factor(unique(x[,2])),cex=0.8,horiz=T)
dev.off()
```

This looks like this:
[image: plot]

As you can see the legend is running off the page.  Does anyone have any solutions that could help optimise the legend so it will always be visible, no matter how many elements are in it?

Comment: Are you certain you want over 100 categories represented in a single plot?  Would grouping into classes (e.g. `cut`) or seperate plots make sense in your case?

Comment: I could potentially group into categories, however there would still be 20+ groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ggplot2, this would put ~7 groups in each row of your legend:

```
x$y <- y
ggplot(x, aes(x=xnum, y=y, group=xdesc, color=xdesc)) + geom_point() + guides(col= guide_legend(position="bottom", nrow=round(length(unique(x$xdesc))/7))) + theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need a solution that works using the legend command, as I will be applying this to a manhattan plot.